# HTTP Request on POST and GET

Tags: http, logging, server

I have a server log and it shows POST and GET

So, if a page is showing POST /ping and GET /xyz

Does this mean that the user agent is Requesting a page is GET and POST is the response from the server?

Because in my server logs, it's showing a lot of POST with million of /ping while the other pages have been GET is a smaller amount of number.

Which should I focus on? Get the POST pages get index if the server shows this to Search engines?

Comment: Nothing related to search engine. Looks like other servers/services are calling your server to check if is alive. That's what a ping endpoint usually do, but he may have no real content. Focus on what you want to index for seo and maybe check if your millions POST are legit

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you learn the difference between HTTP GET and POSTS.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) is quite good.

In summary, the GET requests are pages/data being requested by clients. POSTs are clients sending data to the server, usually expecting data as a response.

Answer (score 0):

In their comment, [Sylwit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1692916/sylwit) pretty much explains what this has to do with search engines. I'm going to just describe the differences between GET and POST

GET and POST are two different types of requests to the server. A GET request is normally used to retrieve information from the server and usually has a series of GET parameters. When you search something on Google you're making a GET request.

```
https://google.com/?q="how+do+i+get"
```

In this case, the GET parameter is the q after the ?, and has a value of "how do i get". It should be noted that a GET request doesn't need these additional parameters (http://google.com) is still a GET request

POST requests, on the other hand, are normally used to send data to the server. You'll see this anytime you send a message, submit a form etc. When I click submit on this answer, I'll be making a POST request to stackoverflow's servers. The parameters for these aren't immediately visible in the browser. POST requests can also return a HTTP response, with a message.

Hope that shows the differences between the two.